# Possible Intersection of Intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose there are two intervals, where one of them is fixed. Is there a way to calculate all possible intersections of the intervals as shown in the figure?[image: figure] ?

Notice that because $a,b$ and $c$ are unknown, different intersection intervals may result. 
PS: The plot is for clarification and does not show all possible case

Comment: Is the answer you are looking for of the form $a \lt 0 \lt b \lt 1 \lt c \lt 2, 1\lt a \lt b \lt 2 \lt c$ (taking the top and bottom examples) and all other rankings as the $abc$ string is slid along?

Comment: yes exactly, taking in consideration that the length of $\left[a,b\right]$ and $\left[b,c\right]$ is variable

Comment: Why do you emphasize a third point within an interval beyond the end points of the interval?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking and what the above picture is supposed to illustrate ... even if other apparently got it and there are already three answers posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two intervals: $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ the intersection is:

- $[a,b]$ if $c\le a$ and $d\ge b$
- $[c,d]$ if $a\le c$ and $b\ge d$
- $[a,d]$ if $c\le a$ and $d\in[a,b]$
- $[c,b]$ if $a\le c$ and $b\in[c,d]$
- $\emptyset$ if $b< c$ or $a>d$.

Answer (score 1):

#### Intersection of two real valued Intervals

Given two real valued intervals
$$
I_1 = [ a_1, b_1] = \{ x \,\left\vert\, a_1 \le x \le b_2 \right. \} \quad I_2 = [ a_2, b_2 ] \quad I_1, I_2 \subset \mathbb{R}
$$
with 
$$
a_1 \le b_1 \wedge a_2 \le b_2 \quad (*)
$$
we define a function 
$$
f(I_1, I_2)
$$

which returns the intersection
$$
I_1 \cap I_2 
= \left\{
\begin{matrix}
I = [a, b] \\
\emptyset
\end{matrix}
\right. 
$$
which is either an interval $I$ with $a \le b$ or the empty set $\emptyset$.

These are the conditions for $f$ to return the empty set:
$$
b_2 < a_1 \vee b_1 < a_2
$$
which mean that $I_2$ lies to the left of $I_1$ or $I_2$ lies to the right of $I_1$, with some space between the intervals.

Otherwise we have
$$
b_2 \ge a_1 \wedge b_1 \ge a_2  \quad (**)
$$

and the endpoints of the intersection interval which $f$ would return in this case are
$$
a = \max\{ a_1, a_2 \} \quad b = \min \{ b_1, b_2 \} 
$$

Proof:

Conditions $(*)$ and $(**)$ imply $a_1 \le b_1 \wedge a_1 \le b_2$ and $a_2 \le b_1 \wedge a_2 \le b_2$, thus $a \le b$.

By definition 
$a \ge a_1 \wedge b \le b_1$, so 
$I \subset I_1$, further 
$a \ge a_2 \wedge b \le b_2$ so
$I \subset I_2$, thus $I \subset I_1 \cap I_2$.

For an arbitrary $x \in I_1 \cap I_2$ we have $a_1 \le x \wedge a_2 \le x$, thus $a \le x$. Further we have $x \le b_1 \wedge x \le b_2$, thus $x \le b$. This means $x \in I$ as well and thus $I_1 \cap I_2 \subset I$. Therefore $I = I_1 \cap I_2$.

#### Application to the Question

Given a pair of neighbouring intervals $[0, 1]$ and $[1, 2]$ as well as a second pair of neighbouring intervals $[a, b]$ and $[b, c]$ their intersection is
$$
([0,1] \cup [1,2]) \cap ([a, b] \cup [b, c]) =
[0,2] \cap [a, c]
$$
and can be determined using the above defined function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of intersections change whenever a bound of one interval set comes in coincidence with a bound of the other interval set, namely $a\equiv0,a\equiv1,a\equiv2,b\equiv0,b\equiv1,b\equiv2,c\equiv0,c\equiv1,c\equiv2$.

These correspond to translations of the second set by amounts $0-a,1-a,2-a,0-b,2-b,0-c,1-c,2-c$. For convenience, these 9 numbers can be ordered and the possible duplicate ignored. There are no more than 9 different configurations.

For a given configuration, enumerating the intersections can be done systematically: starting from the left, advance to the nearest bound and output the two facing intervals (this is called a merge operation). Repeat until both interval sets have been exhausted.

Let us play this game with $0, 1$ vs $a, b$: there are four configurations, with translations $0-a,1-a,0-b,1-b$. Let us choose the first, ie. $0,1$ vs $0,b-a$. There can be three different mergings, $0,b-a,1$, or $0,1=b-a$ or $0,1,b-a$. Let us consider the first case.

Then $(0,b-a)$ is an intersection, while $(b-1,1)$ is not.

You can extend the reasoning to arbitrary translations.

Comment: I like the dynamic approach, which reminds me of the [Sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm).

Comment: @mvw: it can indeed be seen as such. The event points are the interval bounds.